# デバッグ実行直後にCCheckListBoxの☐のみ表示される

Tags: mfc

MFCでCCheckListBoxクラスのコントロール処理を作成し、デバッグ実行したらCCheckListBox内に☐がデフォルトで表示される問題で困っています。

参考画像：
[image: 参考画像]

期待していたCCheckListBoxの状態は、CCheckListBox内に☐がデフォルトで表示されない状態です。
上記の処理作成のために、私が作ったソースは以下です。
ToDoDlg.h(子ダイアログのクラスヘッダー)

```cpp
#pragma once


// ToDoDlg ダイアログ

class ToDoDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(ToDoDlg)

public:
    ToDoDlg(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // 標準コンストラクター
    virtual ~ToDoDlg();

// ダイアログ データ
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_TODO_DIALOG };
#endif

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV サポート


// 実装
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;
    // 生成された、メッセージ割り当て関数
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    /*privateメンバ変数*/
    // To Do項目チェックボックスコントロールリスト変数
    CCheckListBox m_check_list_box;
    // To Do項目表示文字列入力変数
    CString m_add_edit;

    /*privateメンバ関数*/
    afx_msg void OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit();
};
};
```

ToDoDlg.cpp(子ダイアログのクラス実装部分)

```cpp
// ToDoDlg.cpp : 実装ファイル
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LearningPokect.h"
#include "ToDoDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// ToDoDlg ダイアログ

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(ToDoDlg, CDialogEx)

ToDoDlg::ToDoDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_TODO_DIALOG, pParent)
    , m_add_edit(_T(""))
{
}

ToDoDlg::~ToDoDlg()
{
}

void ToDoDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_CAPTION_EDIT, m_add_edit);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TO_DO_LIST, m_check_list_box);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ToDoDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_CAPTION_EDIT, &ToDoDlg::OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL ToDoDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // "バージョン情報..." メニューをシステム メニューに追加します。

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX は、システム コマンドの範囲内になければなりません。
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != nullptr)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // このダイアログのアイコンを設定します。アプリケーションのメイン ウィンドウがダイアログでない場合、
    //  Framework は、この設定を自動的に行います。
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // 大きいアイコンの設定
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // 小さいアイコンの設定

    // TODO: 初期化をここに追加します。
    // MFCのチェックリストコントロールが二重に表示されるバグを直すコード
    // 参考：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951333/cchecklistbox-items-get-overlapped-on-selection-if-app-build-using-visual-studi
    m_check_list_box.SetFont(GetFont());

    return TRUE;  // フォーカスをコントロールに設定した場合を除き、TRUE を返します。
}

// ToDoDlg メッセージ ハンドラー


void ToDoDlg::OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit()
{
    // TODO: ここにコントロール通知ハンドラー コードを追加します。
    /*エディットコントロールから入力文字を取得し、
    チェックボックスリストコントロールの表示文字に設定する*/

    // エディットコントロールの値変数にエディットコントロールで
    // 入力された文字列を代入する
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    CString edit_CString = m_add_edit;

    // 取得した文字列をチェックボックスリストコントロールに設定する
    m_check_list_box.AddString(edit_CString);
}
```

この問題を解決するために、CCheckBoxListコントロールのプロパティや関数を調べてみましたが、解決策が見つかりませんでした。

解決策を教えて頂けるとありがたいです。どうかよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: kunifさんの回答を見る限り「デバッグ実行直後」でなく通常の実行でも発生しそうですが、どうでしょうか？ 質問文を正確にした方が、今後の役に立ちますので。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ダイアログウィンドウを最初に表示する時に`ToDoDlg::OnEnKillfocusCaptionEdit()`が呼ばれるため、`m_check_list_box.AddString(edit_CString);`によって空文字列が追加されるからです。

例えば以下のように`edit_CString`が空文字列なら`m_check_list_box.AddString(edit_CString);`を行わない等の処理を行えば発生しません。

```
if (!edit_CString.IsEmpty())
{
    m_check_list_box.AddString(edit_CString);
}
```

---

なお、学習のため？に色んなことを試しているようですが、上記質問＆回答のように色んな機能の呼び出しに`KillFocus`を使い回すことは予期せぬ問題を呼び込むことになるようなので、今後は止めておいたほうが良いと思われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
お陰様で解決しました。